# Is there a way to cache a query for 24 hrs in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Would like to show a random tip from tips category in wordpress and change it every 24hrs... is it possible?

Here is my query

```
// Random post link 
function randomPostlink(){
$RandPostQuery = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>array('tip'),'posts_per_page' => 1,'orderby'=>'rand'));
while ( $RandPostQuery->have_posts() ) : $RandPostQuery->the_post();
echo the_permalink();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: You can probably use transients

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of **WP Transients API** and use it something like that :

```
 <?php 
    // Check for transient. If none, then execute WP_Query
    if ( false === get_transient( 'special_query_results' ) ) {

          $RandPostQuery = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>array('tip'),'posts_per_page' => 1,'orderby'=>'rand'));

        // Put the results in a transient. Expire after 24 hours.
        set_transient( 'special_query_results', $RandPostQuery , 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    } ?>
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

## Use the Transients API

You can use the class Transients API which can store your data with a expire time in seconds.

So, here is the modified code :

```
<?php
// Your function
function randomPostlink(){

    // Get the cache data
    $rand_tip = get_transient( 'rand_tip' );

    // Launch the request if the data do not exist or the data has expired
    if ( $rand_tip === false ) {

        // Args for the WP_Query
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => array( 'tip' ),
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'orderby'=>'rand'
        );

        // Generate the datas
        $rand_tip = new WP_Query($args);

        // Set the ID of the request
        set_transient( 'rand_tip', $rand_tip, 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );       
    }

    // Loop the posts
    if ( $rand_tip->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $rand_tip->have_posts() ) : $rand_tip->the_post();

            // Echo the permalink
            the_permalink();

        endwhile;

        // Reset the post data
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This works great. If you have multisite you can use `set_site_transient()`, `get_site_transient()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jenis it might be interesting to delete the cache if a new post is published, you can do it with a little hook.

(At least that´s what I am doing when using the Transients API to cache results.)

```
// Delete caches, when a new post is published
function delete_cache_after_publishing_new()  {
delete_transient('your_cache_1');
delete_transient('your_cache_2');
}
add_action('publish_post','delete_cache_after_publishing_new')
```